# Annotation route page substructure matches both routes

Tags: php, symfony, annotations

I'm trying to create route annotations for a controller that handles the pages in my application. The page (read: URL) structure can be multiple levels deep. However it should only accept one variable (slug) for the entire route. I found a solution in adding multiple @route statements, however a page with a certain slug will now match both routes and I think this will cause duplicate content SEO issues. Are there any solutions to my problem that don't cause duplicate content issues? I also rather have just a single @route statement like /{slug}

I have also tried to allow a forward slash (/) in the variable part (symfony calls it a placeholder).

```
/**
  * @Route("/{slug}", name="page", methods={"GET"})
  * @Route("/information/{slug}", name="subpage", methods={"GET"})
  */
```

The slug from a page will match both routes (duplicate content issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add requirements for "slug", [see the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#adding-wildcard-requirements).

Try excluding the path "information" like this:

```
/**
  * @Route("/{slug}", name="page", methods={"GET"}, requirements={"slug"="^(?!information)$"})
  * @Route("/information/{slug}", name="subpage", methods={"GET"})
  */
```